# Ideal Language / IDE for Image Matching for Automation

Tags: image, automation

The intended goal is to create a process that searches in a defined area to match  against static image file. The defined area is dynamic, and ideally the process would execute once a match of a reference image is found. Once the process executes based on image match result, automation via mouse positioning / clicking would occur.

I've been developing primarily in SQL, so I don't have the pre-requisite programming knowledge of what language would be ideal. This is a high-level concept, looking to get any input from those that can assist. Thanks!

Comment: So this is what, an add-in to some other program? A stand-alone process? What is the mouse-click meant to do? Generally I'd use Azure's Cognitive Services, which has many image-processing capabilities like this and is extremely easy to use.

Comment: @McGuireV10 I'm envisioning a stand-alone process. The goal is to automate a repetitious process in a mobile game. Screen-mirroring software is being used, and the stand-alone process needs to be able to identify images in a defined area, along with implementing logic so if Image X is found, Process Y is executed. This is the logic goal to implement. [Imgur Link](https://imgur.com/a/yuxO8)

Comment: Ah. Farming a game. You definitely need a _lot_ more details in your question, then. Since it's mobile, for starters we need to know the platform(s), mobile app dev is a very different proposition and the platforms work very differently. You'll get the best advice if you just name the game, too. Also, image-recognition is overkill since a game is going to involve a very limited set of on-screen content, there are many better ways to skin the cat.

Comment: Also, the platform will most likely determine the language. For example, most Android development uses Java.

Comment: Platform: Android
Software in use: Mobizen (mirroring screen / sending Windows Mouse & Keyboard events to the phone)

I'm going the route of running the process on a PC and mirroring the actions via Mobizen to avoid any kind of detection on the AppDev. side.

Comment: Interesting. Technically this is what Stackoverflow would probably close as "primarily opinion based" ... so, in my opinion :) I'd still go with something like Azure Cognitive Services (it's really easy to use compared to a typical image-processing library like OpenCV, I assume Amazon & Google have equivalents if you prefer the non-MS route), then just whatever language you like (my preference is C# and .NET).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you [Xpresser](https://blog.labix.org/2010/05/18/xpresser-python-library-for-gui-automation-with-image-matching) and as second alternative [sikuli](http://up.csail.mit.edu/sikuli/).

**Xpresser** is a python library for GUI automation with image matching, also you can add [automatic testing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b-xxBBPU9kU) .  Xpresser is a clean room implementation of the concepts explored by Sikuli, in the form of a Python library which can be used standalone, or embedded into other programs and testing frameworks such as Mago.

**Sikuli** you might add [automate testing with selenium](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i6oGa9xU_VY). Sikuli is a visual technology to automate and test graphical user interfaces (GUI) using images (screenshots). Under specific circumstances is a better technology for test automation than Selenium or Watir, which depend on symbolic identifiers.